# Redundant DataContext ? - LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This seems like a pretty basic question, so bear with me...Say I have two (or many) methods in the same class that need a LINQ to SQL DataContext. Additionally, I am needing the DataContext in other classes as well. Does it make sense to create the new DataContext every time?

Should I be creating this DataContext in a different data access class and then inheriting it on each page? I feel like this is the way it should be done, but I'm still learning LINQ to SQL and just looking for some best practices. Can anyone point me to good examples of this?

Thanks,

Code for reference:

```
protected void LoadProducts()
{
    StoreDataClassesDataContext db = new StoreDataClassesDataContext();
    var query = from p in db.Products

            select new
            {
             p.ProductID, 
             p.Description,
             p.Price
            };

    dgProducts.DataSource = query;
    dgProducts.DataBind();
}

protected void LoadSales()
{
    StoreDataClassesDataContext db = new StoreDataClassesDataContext();
    var query = from s in db.Sales 

                select new 
                { 
                s.SaleID,
                s.SaleDate,
                s.Total
                };

    dgSales.DataSource = query;
    dgSales.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You should wrap your context instance inside a `using` block, or manually call `Dispose()` when you're done with it... or are you wiring up your UI directly to your database? ...

Comment: BTW code isn't "for reference" on Code Review - code is *what gets reviewed*, it should be at the core of your post, see our [help/on-topic]. Your question is ok, it's just that you seem to provide the code "for convenience"; know that showing your code is mandatory for your question to be on-topic. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The "for reference" comment was probably just bad wording by me. This is code I have but also indicative of the type of code I am seeing in a few different places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't make a thorough review *right now*, but here's a quick fix that should help you structure things up.

What you have is probably working, but you're mixing-up presentation with data concerns. I don't think these methods should be returning `void`. Picture this:

```
protected IEnumerable<SalesInfo> LoadSales()
{
    using (var db = new StoreDataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Sales.Select(s => new SalesInfo { 
                                                SaleId = s.SaleID,
                                                SaleDate = s.SaleDate,
                                                Total = s.Total })
                             .ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

What you get is a bunch of `SalesInfo` objects that contain your query results. Bind *that* to your UI instead.

It's probably normal you're re-creating the context everytime, you want these things to be as short-lived as possible.

Comment: This is so freakin' important that if everyone would do this it would save me a ton of headache at work right now!! Don't modify instance variables when it makes perfect sense to just return an object!!

Comment: I can see how this makes sense. I am definitely mixing data/UI here. I hadn't been using `using` do to this section from [Jon Skeet's C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89). I may (likely) misunderstood when/not it was okay to omit `using`. After searching around some more on the topic,  it seems that even in the right scenario when you don't **need** the `using` and its auto `dispose()` call, you should probably just do it anyway?

Comment: @FreeMars correct: with your current code if you wrap it with `using` or call `Dispose()` I believe you'd get some `ObjectDisposedException`, because your UI would be fetching the data... but that is *bad*! Rule of thumb, if it implements `IDisposable`, do everything you can to call that `Dispose()` method as soon as possible.